# Nullable boolean with PostGres in Symfony 2.0

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I have a class with the following attribute :

```
/**
* @var boolean
*
* @ORM\Column(name="validated", type="boolean", nullable=true)
*/
private $validated;
```

I would like it to be null by default in the database but whatever I do I keep getting a FALSE value when inserting it as NULL.

Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Default values come from your entities, so this should do it

```
private $validated = null;
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for your help! I have already tried that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Never used postgre but it appears that there is a function which return false for null value (convertSingleBooleanValue) as shown here :

```
private function convertSingleBooleanValue($value, $callback)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            return $callback(false);
        }

        if (is_bool($value) || is_numeric($value)) {
            return $callback($value ? true : false);
        }

        if (!is_string($value)) {
            return $callback(true);
        }

        //etc...
    }
```

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/625

So as this is most likely your problem, you should check if there is a way to bypass this.

As for postgresql http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-boolean.html there is still an "unknown" value that is null.